# In Ruby how do I find the index of one of an array of elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby

In Ruby 2.4, how do I find the earliest index of an element of an array in another array?  That is, if any element of an array occurs in the other array, I want to get the first index.  I thought find_index might do it, but

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
a.find_index("a")
# => 0
a.find_index(["b", "c"])
# => nil
```

In the above example, I would expect to see the output "1" because the element "b" occurs at index 1 in the array "a".

Comment: You did `a.find_index("a")` to find the index of `"a"` in `["a", "b", "c"]`, so why are you doing `a.find_index(["b", "c"])` and not `a.find_index("b")` to find the index of `"b"`? The `a.find_index(["b", "c"])` is looking for an element in array `a` that looks like `["b", "c"]` which isn't there. That's a sub-array, not an element.

Comment: Are you trying to find the first occurrence of `b,c` sequentially, or simply the first entry in the given array?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`find_index` takes a single element. You could find the minimum by doing something like

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
to_find = ["b", "c"]
to_find.map {|i| a.find_index(i) } .compact.min # => 1
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland no real opinion on `compact`; I see it used quite often and it seems clear enough to me. Also, fyi `[nil,nil,nil].compact.min` returns `nil`. So no exception afaict.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you. As it was in error, I've deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `find_index` and pass the needed value from the array:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
p a.find_index('a')
p a.find_index('b')
p a.find_index('c')
# => 0
# => 1
# => 2
```

You can use `map` to get every element inside your `a` array and then to get the index corresponding to each element:

```
p a.map{|e| a.find_index(e)}
# => [0, 1, 2]
```

Another possible way to handle it could be to use the [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
a.each_with_index{|e,i| puts "Element: #{e}, Index: #{i}"}
# => Element: a, Index: 0
# => Element: b, Index: 1
# => Element: c, Index: 2
```

If you want to check the indexes for each element in `["b", "c"]` using the `["a", "b", "c"]` array, you can map the first one, get the array values, and then use the `a,b,c` to check those indexes:

```
p ["b", "c"].map{|e| ["a", "b", "c"].find_index(e) }
# => [1, 2]
```

You can also see [`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-index) and [`Enumerable#find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index).

Comment: Someone's cranky. I've voted up to restore balance in the universe. I think it's because it's not addressing calling it with an array.

Comment: The questions asks for a single number (an index) to be returned, possibly to be used in subsequent calculations. You have not done that. I expect that's the reason for the downvote. Also, `a.map{|e| a.find_index(e)}` is of no value.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-index) with a block.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a.index { |x| ['b', 'c'].include?(x) }
#=> 1
```

Quote from the docs:

> If a block is given instead of an argument, returns the index of the first object for which the block returns true. Returns nil if no match is found.

---

As Cary pointed out in his comment it is not the most performant algorithm to compare all elements in `a` against all elements in `['b', 'c']` (this would lead to `O(n*m)`). Depending on the size of both arrays if might sense to build a more efficient data structure first. Using a `Set` instead of an Array has some cost in creating the `set` upfront, but makes the comparison in the block much faster (overall `O(n+m)`):

```
require 'set'

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
set = Set.new(['b', 'c'])
a.index { |x| set.include?(x) }
#=> 1
```

Comment: If `b = ['b', 'c']`, this is preferable to enumerating `b` looking for matches in `a`. If `a` and `b` contain `n` and `m` elements respectively, and the element at index `i` of `a` is the first to match an element of `b` (`i <= n`), `i*m` operations are required. If `b` is enumerated, `n*m` operations are required. This is therefore faster that enumerating `b` regardless of `n` and `m`. If `n*m` is large I would suggest first computing `require set; sb = b.to_set`, and using `sb.include?(x)` to speed that operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could find index of all elements of array `b` in the array `a`, and find the min index to find the index at which an element from array `b`  occurred first in array `a`.

Something like below:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["b", "c"]

b.map { |x| a.find_index(x) }.min
#=> 1
```